# QML make dynamic created objects Dragable

Tags: qt, qml, drag

I'm creating objects using JS in QML with following script:

```
     var component;
var gauge;

function createVerticalGauge(setWidth) {
    component = Qt.createComponent("VerticalBarGauge.qml");
    if (component.status == Component.Ready)
        finishCreation(setWidth);
    else
        component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
}

function finishCreation(setWidth) {
    if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
        gauge = component.createObject(root, {"x": 100, "y": 100});
        gauge.width = setWidth;
        if (gauge == null) {
            // Error Handling
            console.log("Error creating object");
        }
    } else if (component.status == Component.Error) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
    }
}
```

This is the QML page that executes the script using a Pie Menu.

```
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick 2.8
import "CreateVerticalGauge.js" as CreateVerticalGaugeScript

Rectangle {
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    color: "black"

    id: dashboard
    anchors.fill: parent

    DropArea {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: touchArea
        anchors.fill: parent


        onClicked: pieMenu.popup(mouseX, mouseY), console.log("clicked")
       }

    PieMenu {
        id: pieMenu

        MenuItem {
            text: "Add vertial bar"
            onTriggered: CreateVerticalGaugeScript.createVerticalGauge(300);
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Add horizontal bar"
            onTriggered: print("Action 2")
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Add dial gauge"
            onTriggered: print("Action 3")
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: "Remove"
            onTriggered: print("Action 4")
        }

    }



}
```

This is the object that is created by the script:

```
import QtQuick 2.8
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4



    Rectangle {
        id: rev
        width: 100
        height: 80
        color: "transparent"
        antialiasing: false
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top

        Drag.active: parent.touchArea.drag.active

        Gauge {
            id: revgauge
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            orientation : Qt.Horizontal
            minorTickmarkCount: 4
            tickmarkStepSize : 5000
            //labelStepSize: 50
            minimumValue: 0
            maximumValue: 10000

            //value: Dashboard.revs
            Behavior on value {
                NumberAnimation {
                    duration: 5
                }
            }
            Text {
                //text:"RPM " + Dashboard.revs
                font.pixelSize: (parent.height / 3)
                anchors.top : parent.top
                // anchors.top : parent.top
                font.bold: true
                font.family: "Eurostile"
                color: "white"
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }
              style: GaugeStyle {
                valueBar: Rectangle {
                   implicitWidth:  rev.height /3
                    color: Qt.rgba(revgauge.value / revgauge.maximumValue, 0, 1 - revgauge.value / revgauge.maximumValue, 1)
                }
            }
      }
    }
```

The creation is working and the object is created on the QML page.

How can I make the dynamic created object dragable on the QML Page?
After the object has been created on my screen, how can I make it dragable.

Comment: You can provide a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: Thank for the hint. I made a verifiable example of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what creation method is used. The easiest approach would be to have the created items be draggable to begin with. You should put a mouse area into each of them and set it to drag that particular item.

A solution with only a single mouse area would involve some kind of logic to find the item at the drag start position if any, and set that as a drag target if found. This is a tad more complex, so I suggest going for the previous implementation.

[image]

```
  Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Repeater {
      model: 20
      delegate: Rectangle {
        width: main.width
        height: 2
        color: "black"
        y: Math.round(Math.random() * (main.height - 10))
        MouseArea {
          width: parent.width
          height: parent.height + 10 // easier to get
          anchors.centerIn: parent
          drag.target: parent
          drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I made a mousearea in the qml but it didn't work https://github.com/BastianGschrey/PowerCAN/blob/master/VerticalBarGauge.qml  do you see whats wrong?

Comment: You are setting anchors. Anchored items are... well... anchored in place, they cannot move.

Comment: Sir! Thank you..  :-)